# How to read from a file every 30ms and process it in a new thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a file with several integers (each one in a new line). I want to read the file every 30ms and process each of these integers.

Software : C++

Present idea :
1) In the main(), use file input/ouput to continuously read from the file and sleep for 30ms everytime.
2) Everytime I read an integer, I create a new thread which processes this integer.

Will the main() be suspended till the new thread finishes its operation? or will it also run in parallel?
Is there any better approach to doing the same process?

Comment: If you are making a thread for processing each integer (which you are saying) then the main thread will continue to run. However, if your processing time gets larger than 30ms, it will only make more threads and it will run out of resources.

Comment: Do you actually need to check for a new integer every 30ms or simply process them at that specific rate?

Either way,  I'd have 1 thread checking the file and pushing integers into a queue that the processing thread would read from. I see no reason to have more than 2 threads here.

Comment: I see no reason to have threads at all. They can only be useful if you need to do multiple things at the same time. You are not doing that. Also what Evert said: If one thread cannot do it in 30ms then multiple threads cannot do it either.

Comment: @Evert: Wrong. If processing takes an average of 60 ms, you will have an average of 2 live threads. Assuming at least two CPU cores, that won't run out of resources.

Comment: @Evert : True. Processing time won't be more than 30ms. It will return to the main before the time frame.

Comment: @KristapsBaumanis : It is a live environment. I need to keep getting the integers at a constant rate and process them.

Comment: @nwp : I wrote a whole program without threads and it works perfectly fine but while integrating into the system, there need to be threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea works in theory. You do create a lot of threads, which is inefficient. And if you don't have enough CPU cores, at a certain moment the main thread won't get scheduled every 30 ms anymore so you'll fall behind.

The better solution is to have a threadpool whose threads pick up numbers that the main thread has made available.